# Cakephp CMS Plugin or Component available ? or Croogo Cakephp CMS is good?

Tags: cakephp, content-management-system, cakephp-2.0

Is any predefined Content management systems in cakephp ? . I find an open source `http://croogo.org/` is an Cakephp CMS. any one have idea on these, because i could not find any documentation on this **Croogo**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one in bakery... Please try this.. This may help you.
http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/y2k_2000/2011/10/28/quickapps_cms_-_cakephp_2_0

Answer (score 6):

Have a look:--

http://blog.dreamcss.com/content-management-system/cakephp-based-cms/

http://cakephpcms.com/